# Memory leaks playing video with a MediaSession using SharpDX

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, ms-media-foundation, sharpdx

I'm suffering a memory leak and have so far had zero luck tracing it.  It seems to be related to freeing a topology.

Basically I have a video player that can have multiple topologies attached to it.  Each time I call play I re-create the topology (using activate objects for audio and video) as follows:

```
    private Topology BuildTopology( TimeSpan startTime, TimeSpan endTime, IntPtr hWnd )
    {
        if ( _topology != null )
        {
            _topology.Dispose();
            _topology   = null;
        }

        MediaFactory.CreateTopology( out _topology );

        SharpDX.MediaFoundation.MediaSource mediaSource;
        {
            SourceResolver resolver = new SourceResolver();

            ObjectType otype;
            ComObject source = (ComObject)resolver.CreateObjectFromURL(FileName, SourceResolverFlags.MediaSource, null, out otype);
            mediaSource = source.QueryInterface<SharpDX.MediaFoundation.MediaSource>();
            resolver.Dispose();
            source.Dispose();
        }

        PresentationDescriptor presDesc;
        mediaSource.CreatePresentationDescriptor(out presDesc);

        for (var i = 0; i < presDesc.StreamDescriptorCount; i++)
        {
            SharpDX.Mathematics.Interop.RawBool selected;
            StreamDescriptor desc;
            presDesc.GetStreamDescriptorByIndex(i, out selected, out desc);

            if (selected)
            {
                var majorType = desc.MediaTypeHandler.MajorType;

                TopologyNode sourceNode;
                MediaFactory.CreateTopologyNode( TopologyType.SourceStreamNode, out sourceNode );

                sourceNode.Set( TopologyNodeAttributeKeys.Source, mediaSource );
                sourceNode.Set( TopologyNodeAttributeKeys.PresentationDescriptor, presDesc );
                sourceNode.Set( TopologyNodeAttributeKeys.StreamDescriptor, desc );

                if ( startTime != TimeSpan.Zero )
                    sourceNode.Set( TopologyNodeAttributeKeys.Mediastart, startTime.Ticks );
                if ( endTime != TimeSpan.Zero )
                    sourceNode.Set( TopologyNodeAttributeKeys.Mediastop, endTime.Ticks );

                TopologyNode outputNode;
                MediaFactory.CreateTopologyNode(TopologyType.OutputNode, out outputNode);


                if (majorType == MediaTypeGuids.Video)
                {
                    Activate activate;
                    MediaFactory.CreateVideoRendererActivate( hWnd, out activate );
                    outputNode.Object = activate;


                    IsVideo = true;
                }

                if (majorType == MediaTypeGuids.Audio)
                {
                    Activate activate;
                    MediaFactory.CreateAudioRendererActivate( out activate );
                    //activate.Dispose();

                    outputNode.Object = activate;
                }

                outputNode.Set( TopologyNodeAttributeKeys.NoshutdownOnRemove, false );

                _topology.AddNode( sourceNode );
                _topology.AddNode( outputNode );
                sourceNode.ConnectOutput( 0, outputNode, 0 );

                sourceNode.Dispose();
                outputNode.Dispose();
            }

            desc.Dispose();
        }

        presDesc.Dispose();
        mediaSource.Dispose();
        return _topology;
    }
```

Whats strange is that despite each time ensuring that the previous topology has been freed I get a memory leak that slowly builds up until my application throws an out of memory error.

My play function is as follows:

```
    private void Play( TimeSpan ts )
    {
        if (State != MediaState.Stopped)
        {
            _session.Stop();
            _clock.Dispose();
        }

        // Set the new song.
        _session.SetTopology( SessionSetTopologyFlags.ClearCurrent, null );
        //_session.ClearTopologies();
        _session.SetTopology( SessionSetTopologyFlags.Immediate, _currentVideo.Topology );

        // Get the clock.
        _clock = _session.Clock.QueryInterface< PresentationClock >();

        // Start playing.
        var varStart = new Variant();
        varStart.Value  = (long)ts.Ticks;
        _session.Start( null, varStart );
    }
```

I have "EnableObjectTracking" and "UseThreadStaticObjectTracking" turned on but there is no build up of objects occurring.  Only my session and the last played topology ever show up.

Interstingly the memory leajk was much much quicker until I turned on "EnableReleaseOnFinalizer".  Now it takes several hundred play cycles to run out of memory which is a vast improvement but still no good to me.

Has anyone got any idea what I'm doing wrong?  This is driving me slightly mad.  The appliaction is ready apart from for this memory leak and I can't release with this problem there.

***Edit***: I should add that this seems to be related to video as there doesn't appear to be a memory leak (or its VERY small by comparison) when I'm playing audio files rather than video.

Comment: Many MF objects require shutdown call, e.g. `IMFMediaSession::Shutdown` and just disposal will leave the object floating around forever (circular references and so on). I am guessing it's one of these cases. I have hard time finding out anything from code snippets (they are not even original MF but a wrapper) but I don't see `_session.Shutdown` and this is one of the most important to look for. Then there is `IMFMediaSource::Shutdown` too...

Comment: @RomanR: I tried creating a whole new session everytime I wanted to play and this caused a leak too.  As such I am just swapping the topology around within the session.  the session is intended to hang around.  As I'm not creating a new session each time, though, this should not end up leaking memory!

Comment: Hmm It looks likely this was the MediaSource remaining open.  A colleague noticed you couldn't overwrite the source file even after the topology was closed.  I added some code to specifically shutdown the MediaSource and the memory leak is looking like its gone.  Going to run a soak test after lunch to see whether the memory is just creeping up very slowly!

Comment: Hi, if you have solved the issue.  Add a direct answer to this for future reference for anyone needing to answer this.  Thanks!